# Permutation Issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

So I have a program here that is supposed to print to the screen permutations of a user input word that can be 4 to 10 characters long and there are supposed to be as many permutations as there are letters in the word. I almost have complete success, but there is one issue. When it prints the permutations, after the first about 2 permutations, it starts to not use all the letters and/or the same letter twice.

For example, if the user input word is "bill", the output is as follows:

llib     illb     ibll     lbii

The fourth is is obviously not correct. The problem is more apparent with words that have more letters. I need it to only use the letters it has once. How do I go about fixing this in my code? Here is my code.

```
int main(void)
{
string word;
string randword;
string reverse;
int length;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
string randCH;

    cout << "Enter any word 4 to 10 letters in length: ";
    cin >> word;

    //Checks if word is less than 4 or greater than 10
    while (1)
    {
        /*The code here is in the final program and I know it works. The problem is not here*/
    }

    length = word.length();

    //Uses reverse function
    reverse = reverseit(word);
    /*reverseit is a function outside of main that makes the word backwards*/

    //Prints all permutations
    cout << endl << reverse << "     ";
    for (i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        {
            randCH = word.substr(rand() % length, 1);
            cout << randCH;
        }
        cout << "     ";
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: With n letters, there are usually n! permutations, not n. The number of (unique) permutations goes down if letters repeat, but to get only n permutations from n letters, all but one letter will have to be the same. (Then you have n places to put the odd letter.)

Comment: "randomly (but with a little bias) sample N letters from this string with replacement" is not a permutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `std::next_permutation` which is already built to achieve this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    sort(word.begin(),word.end());

    do {
        cout << word <<endl;
    } while(next_permutation(word.begin(),word.end()));
}
```